# PHP function not getting called through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have ajax call to PHP function as :

```
$.ajax({

  url: 'Link',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'json',
  data: {'txtFromOrderDate' : '2014-08-01','txtToOrderDate' : '2014-08-05'},
  success: function() {
  window.location = 'Link';
  }

  });
```

PHP function as:

```
public function createZipAction($txtFromOrderDate,$txtToOrderDate)
    {


    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
    $date = date('m:d:Y H:i:s', time());



    $exportBatch = $date; 

    $order = $this->getTableGateway('order');

    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('order')
        ->join('user', 'order.user_id = user.id', array('email'))

         ->where ("order.created between ".$txtFromOrderDate." and '2014-08-03' ");
         //->where ('order.created between '.$txtFromOrderDate.'  and '.$txtToOrderDate);


    $data = $order->selectWith($select)->toArray();

    $batchDir = __DIR__ . '/../../../../../data/export/batch/' . $exportBatch;
    if(is_dir($batchDir) == false)
    mkdir($batchDir);

    $csvFile = fopen($batchDir . '/order.csv', 'w');

    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $record) {
        if($i==0) fputcsv($csvFile, $this->getCsvHeader($record));
        fputcsv($csvFile, $this->updateCsvLine($record));
        $pngTmpFile = $this->saveTmpImage($record['plate_id']);
        $this->savePlatePdf($pngTmpFile, $exportBatch, $record['id']);

        unlink($pngTmpFile);
        $i++;
    }

    fclose($csvFile);

    $filter = new \Zend\Filter\Compress(array(
        'adapter' => 'Zip',
        'options' => array(
            'archive' => $batchDir . '.zip'
        )
    ));

    $filter->filter($batchDir);

    $fileToDownload=$batchDir . '.zip';

    $this->downloadOrderCSVAction($fileToDownload);

    echo "exported: $i records.";
    die();
    }
```

Here when i supply dates to this function, Its not getting dates.

But when i write dates hard-code in php function as:

```
$txtFromOrderDate='2014-08-01'

$txtToOrderDate='2014-08-05'
```

Then further function works as expected.

what can be the issue???

Please help me.

Comment: `$txtFromOrderDate = $_POST['txtFromOrderDate'];` etc ... when you POST to PHP, those variables are not set as globals, but are set in the $_POST array.

Comment: Show us the code where you supply the method with the POST variables. Also, the query does not appear to be safe. Someone can send a malicious date (i.e. SQL code) to the script and do some nasty stuff. You should sanitize the input before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you POST to PHP (via AJAX in your case), those data variables are not set as globals. They are set in the `$_POST` array.

You can use them directly or set them to your global variables (just ensure you check they exist before-hand).

```
if (isset($_POST['youVariable')) {
    $yourVariable = $_POST['yourVariable'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was new with PHP